# Javascript | case-insensitive string replace

Tags: javascript

I have this function :

```
function boldString(str, find){
   return str.replace(find, '<b>'+find+'</b>');
}
```

It works, except that it is case sensitive.

I could to-lower-case the str and find text before running the replace, **But I want the function to return the original capitalization in the str field**

So if I pass in 'Apple' for the str, and 'ap' for the find, I want the function to return '**Ap**ple'.

Comment: What does this have to do with JQuery?

Comment: If you return the `Apple` then the function is not replacing anything, you are returning the string, are you looking for `includes` method.

Comment: @Agalo When I call the function, I set a string equal to the return variable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With a case-insensitive regular expression:

```js
function boldString(str, find) {
  var reg = new RegExp('('+find+')', 'gi');
  return str.replace(reg, '<b>$1</b>');
}
console.log(boldString('Apple', 'ap'))
```